# How to get results from Access mdb file to Visual Basic form

Tags: vba

I am creating sort of like a database for work. I work as an IT Technician and we have many computers that come in for reimaging. We were losing many of them so I decided to make a "database" to keep tracks of everything. These computers come in with trouble tickets and I want the user to be able to search by *ticket number* or by *serial number*. My application tells me when the field is empty, it tells me when there are no results, but I can't figure out how to make it so that if it finds a result, I want it to display all fields of that row in textboxes. If it finds more than one results, I want it to show the most recent one (the rows also include the day it was brought in). Here is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("No input", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Search")
        txtSearch.Focus()
    ElseIf InStr(txtSearch.Text, "'") Then
        MsgBox("Invalid character: '", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Search")
        txtSearch.Text = ""
        txtSearch.Focus()
    ElseIf rdoTicketNumber.Checked = True Then
        Dim sql = "select * from Tickets where Ticket_Number = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        con.ConnectionString = ("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=../Database.mdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            If dr.Read = False Then
                MsgBox("No Results", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Search")
                txtSearch.Text = ""
                txtSearch.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    ElseIf rdoSerialNumber.Checked = True Then
        Dim sql = "select * from Tickets where Asset_Serial = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        con.ConnectionString = ("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=../Database.mdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            If dr.Read = False Then
                MsgBox("No Results", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Search")
                txtSearch.Text = ""
                txtSearch.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are using VB.Net, If yes your code should be improved, it has many things to become better ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just want to filter your results of the query-string:

```
Dim sql = "select * from Tickets where Asset_Serial = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
```

To filter it for recent one, change it to something like this:

```
Dim sql = "select TOP(1) * from Tickets where Asset_Serial = '" & txtSearch.Text & "' ORDER BY <yourDateField> DESC"
```

That you should change `<yourDateField>` to name of that date field in your `Tickets` table, and also if you have just day of ticket and you want to filter the result to most recent in that date I suggest you this:

```
Dim sql = "select TOP(1) * from Tickets where Asset_Serial = '" & txtSearch.Text & "' ORDER BY <yourDateField> DESC, <yourPKField> DESC"
```

Comment: Don't forgot to apply it to all of your query strings ;).